# Ms Access Query is not sorting after adding (All)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I created the following query to use in a dropdown :

```
SELECT [SynergyReport 2].ObjectID FROM [SynergyReport 2] 
UNION SELECT "(All)" FROM [SynergyReport 2] 
ORDER BY [SynergyReport 2].[ObjectID];
```

The problem is it doesn't sort me the data ascending. If I use this query without the "(All)" I get the data displayed ascending:

```
SELECT [SynergyReport 2].ObjectID
FROM [SynergyReport 2]
ORDER BY [SynergyReport 2].[ObjectID];
```

Any Idee on where the problem is? The field I'm querying and want to sort is a "number field"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
SELECT "(All)" 
FROM [SynergyReport 2] 
UNION 
SELECT [SynergyReport 2].ObjectID 
FROM [SynergyReport 2] 
ORDER BY [SynergyReport 2].[ObjectID];
```